# How to create seperate controller for admin under app/controller/admin

Tags: routes, cakephp-2.0, hmvc

I am working with CakePHP. I want to create subfolder for admin in controller folder for all admin controllers. I have tried `Prefix Routing` method for this, but it dint work for folders.

I have tried using this: https://github.com/ichikaway/AutoAppBuild, it worked but only for the controller which i have mentioned in routes file.

I want to do something like this:

> http://my_site.com/ -----> for frontend
>
> http://my_site.com/admin -----> for admin .

I created a subdirectory under "controllers" dir and added following line
to routes.php

> $Route->connect('/admin/*', array('controller' => 'admin/dashboard',
>   'action' => 'display'));

Of course, it doesn't work. Cakephp is confused about the directory and
class name.

Can anyone please help me out?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its wrong method to create admin panel. follow below setup to setup admin.

1) go to core.php and uncomment following code

```
//Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('admin'));
```

2) now if you want to create login form for admin go to ur users controller and create one method which name start with 'admin_' for example admin_index

3) now open your routes.php and write following code

```
Router::connect('/admin', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index', 'admin'=>'true'));
```

now when you write http://www.example.com/admin it will go to users and admin_index method